# Which modelfield can store video playback time in django? Or, displaying TimeField WITHOUT a clock associated

Tags: html, django, momentjs

I'm surprised that I can't find an answer on SO, but I'm trying to store some information when a user taps/clicks somewhere on my video player. To do this I store the current playback time in a `TimeField` like so:

```
class TappableItem(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    **video_time = models.TimeField()**
    position = models.FloatField()
```

And I save it using momentjs:

```
get formattedVideoTime() {
    const seconds = this.video.currentTime;
    return moment.utc(seconds*1000).format('HH:mm:ss.SSS');
}
```

So the problem is this: it saves in the DB in a format I want, for example `00:02:41` but when I try to display it in my HTML template, it converts to a date and prints something like `12:02 AM` or `midnight`. I can't find a way to override this behavior.

Should I be using a different modelField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) might be a appropriate field to use here.